# Cannot add value to Data.DataRow in DataTable C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I cant seem to add a value to a datatable in C#. I have done my research and cannot figure out what I am missing. I can print the value to console but when I try to assign and add System.Data.DataRow. Its probably a simple solution but I cannot figure it out to save the life of me.

worktable is new datatable

```
foreach(var ts in timeSeries_ind)
        {
            Bar mbar = ts as Bar;
            DataRow newr = workTable.NewRow();
            newr["Date/Time"] = mbar.DateTime;
            Console.WriteLine(mbar.DateTime);
            workTable.Rows.Add(newr); //newr
            Console.WriteLine(newr.ToString());

        }
```

Firstline prints fine to console
Second when trying to view Data.DataRow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't print a complete DataRow, you need to specify which field of the DataRow you want to print. For example `(string)newr["Date/Time"]`.

Comment: OMG, Thank you thank you! I cannot believe I was forgetting the [""].